# How to avoid killing the running application when starting the Appium Inspector session?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I would like to launch Appium Inspector session to attach to the currently running Android app on my device. The problem I'm facing is that whenever I start the session, the running app is getting killed and launched again. Is there any way to avoid that?

I'm currently using the following config:

```json
{
  "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
  "platformName": "android",
  "appium:app": "/my/path/to/apk",
  "appium:noReset": true
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure, but those capabilities might help:

```
"appium:noReset": true,
"appium:autoLaunch": false,
```

Also, remove `appium:app` capability and try to run without it (possibly appium will just create an empty session without app and will wait for new instructions).

If it doesn't work, replace `appium:app` with:

```
"appium:appPackage": ...,
"appium:appActivity":...
```

**Update**

The final capabilities set

```
"appium:autoLaunch": false, // to disable app relaunch on Appium session start
"appium:noReset": true,
"appium:dontStopAppOnReset": true, // to prevent closing the app Appium Inspector's session stopped
"appium:app"
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding just `"appium:autoLaunch": false` helped with the app being restarted at the beginning. Later on, I also figured out I additionally needed `"appium:dontStopAppOnReset": true` to prevent closing the app when I was closing the Appium Inspector's session. I left `appium:app` and `appium:noReset` as they were.

Comment: @AndrzejZabost great! I'll update my answer with the final capabilities list, to share this with the community.